# What does the "either" in this sentence mean?

Tags: pronouns

The whole paragraph is like this:

> An experiment has three possible outcomes, l, J, and K. The
>   probabilities of the outcomes are 0.25, 0.35, and 0.40, respectively.
>   If the experiment is to be performed twice and the successive outcomes
>   are independent, what is the probability that K will not be an outcome
>   either time?

I'm not sure about the `either` in  `K will not be an outcome either time`.

Which of the following is the right meaning?

(1) In any of these two times, K will not be an outcome.

Or

(2) K will not be an outcome in both time, which means, K can be the outcome in one time at most.

The right answer is 0.64, which supports (1), but I suspect it's wrong..

Does anyone have ideas about this?

Comment: Option 1 sounds close.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your first answer is correct.

> "What is the probability that K will not be an outcome either time?"

By "either time," this question is referring to the possibility of K being an outcome in either one of the two performances; therefore, K cannot be in either of the outcomes with falsifying the answer.